# How to sum the same column under different grouping

Tags: sql

```
   |col.a |col.b |col.c |col.d
Q1 123     1      F      1
Q2 123     3      G      1
Q3 234     0.2    F      2
Q4 135     1      F      2

When col.d=1, sum col.b (group by col.a), if that >0 then 'OK' else 'NOT'
When col.d=2, sum col.b (group by col.c), if that >2 then 'pass' else 'fail'.
End as IDT
```

I have no idea how to use the combination of Case when, sum and group by to get the IDT column.

Comment: What is the expected output you want?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Given half the query, how do you think we can help?  Read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Not exaclty sure if I understood you correctly. Do you mean something like this?

```sql
select 
    case 
        when sum(col.b) > 0 then 'OK'
        else 'NOT'
    end as IDT
from table
where col.d = 1
group by col.a
union all
select 
    case 
        when sum(col.b) > 2 then 'pass'
        else 'fail'
    end as IDT
from table
where col.d = 2
group by col.c
```